# Delete file with specific extension in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, short-filenames

I would like to recursively delete all files with a specific extension in a batch file.

I am aware of the following command:

```
del /s *.ext
```

However, this does on Windows also delete files with other extensions like e.g. .ext1 or .ext2 . The reason for this seems to be that the 8.3 file name of such a file ends with .ext and therefore also the files with longer extensions are matched.

I am looking for a replacement to the command above that recursively deletes all files with .ext extension but keeps files with longer extensions.

Comment: Good question, and it seems only to be relevant to short extensions (like three letters): I tried with "test.tralala" and "test.tralalala" and "del /s *.tralala" only removed one file.

Comment: Bad question. This is a programming site. Ask on https://superuser.com.

Comment: @Mark: I disagree. It's a piece of code that doesn't quite work as intended. It describes the actual outcome, the desired outcome and the shortest code to replicate the issue.

Comment: It's not code at all. Its a typed command.

Comment: @Mark OP requires a batch-file to delete the files, he tried the _"command"_ in the batch-file and clearly did not do what OP wanted, hence this question is a valid StackOverflow question.

Comment: It a typed command. It is not programing. It is not interesting as it showns no knowledge of Windows.

Comment: @mark, what is a `batch-file` then? it is a `file`, with `batch`es of _"commands"_, launched in sequence... no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [where](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html) command works a bit differently (in regards to wildcards and short-names). Put a `for /f` loop around, and you're done. Your example would then translate to:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where /r . *.ext') do ECHO del "%%a"
```

Note: I disarmed the `del` command by just echoing it. Remove the `ECHO` after troubleshooting, when you are sure it does exactly what you want.

Comment: I accept this answer because it's the simplest way to solve my specific problem - Compo's answer is not relevant for my use case. +1 for both other answers anyhow, since they both add valuable information for similar problems.

Comment: @FourtyTwo, my answer is 100% relevant for all scenarios. What you mean is that you do not care about making the code robust, because you cannot envisage, in your specific case, ever having a file named `something.ext.com`, `something.ext.exe`, `something.ext.bat`, `something.ext.cmd`, `something.ext.vbs`, `something.ext.vbe`, `something.ext.js`, `something.ext.jse`, `something.ext.wsf`, `something.ext.wsh`, `something.ext.msc`, or `something.ext.AnyOtherExtensionHeldInPathExt`, anywhere within the entire tree rooted at your unspecified current directory.

Answer (score 2):

This also uses `where.exe`, but takes account of an issue not mentioned in another answer.

The issue is that `where` searches append each extension listed under `%PATHEXT%` to your `.ext` glob/spec. So whilst it will delete your target files, excluding files like `.ext1` and `.ext2` etc. it will now include for example, `*.ext.com`, `*.ext.exe`, `*.ext.bat`, `*.ext.cmd`, `*.ext.vbs`, `*.ext.vbe`, `*.ext.js`, `*.ext.jse`, `*.ext.wsf`, `*.ext.wsh`, and `*.ext.msc` etc.

The fix is to simply empty the content of `%PATHEXT%` before issuing the command. The following method does so within the `For` loop parenthsized command. As that is ran in another `cmd.exe` instance, it will not affect the instance in which the rest of your script resides:

```batch-file
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('"(Set PATHEXT=) & "%__APPDIR__%where.exe" /F /R "C:\SourceDir" "*.ext" 2>NUL"') Do @Del /A /F %%G
```

Obviously, you would modify, `C:\SourceDir` to contain the root location you require. The other current answers, use the current directory. If you want that, change it to `.`, or if you want the directory base as that of your batch file, change it to `%~dp0.`. Please do not remove any doublequotes.

---

Here are some alternative method examples, *(please remember to adjust the drive/path/extension as needed)*

If you wish to stick with the more traditional `Dir` command, then you could pipe the results through the `findstr.exe` utility, to exclude those matching the 8.3 names:

```batch-file
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('"Dir /B /S /A:-D "C:\SourceDir\*.ext" 2> NUL | "%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe" /I /L /E ".ext""') Do @Del /A /F "%%G"
```

You could also use the `forfiles.exe` utility for the task:

```batch-file
@"%__APPDIR__%forfiles.exe" /P "C:\SourceDir" /S /M "*.ext" /C "\"%__APPDIR__%cmd.exe\" /C \"If @IsDir==FALSE Del /A /F @File\""
```

Or this excruciatingly slow `WMIC.exe` utility method:

```batch-file
@"%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe" DataFile Where "Drive='C:' And Path Like '\\SourceDir\\%%' And Extension='ext'" Delete 1> NUL 2>&1
```

Comment: If interested parties wish to see a demonstration of the `where` issue I mentioned, create a two line batch file **1.** `@MD "Temporary\SubFolder"&For %%G In (.ext .ext1 .ext2 .ext.com)Do @CD.>"Temporary\madeupname%%G"&CD.>"Temporary\Subfolder\anothername%%G` **2.** `@"%__APPDIR__%where.exe" /R "Temporary" "*.ext"&Pause`. When you run it, you should clearly see the `.ext.com` files listed. This means, without undefining/emptying `%PATHEXT%`, you would effectively be deleting executable files with names containing the string `.ext`. _(Don't forget to remove the Temporary directory afterwards)_.

Answer (score 1):

[`Stephans`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63047981/delete-file-with-specific-extension-in-batch-file/63049204#63049204) answer is the shorter version, but you can use `findstr`'s regex as well to match that the end of the name should be `.ext`

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s ^| findstr /IRC:"\.ext$"') do echo del "%%~i"
```